# How can I make a RecyclerView appear as if it wraps around a cylinder? (Horizontal Wheel picker)

Tags: android, animation, widget, android-recyclerview, linear-algebra

I want to create a horiontal wheel-picker in my app.

So far, I have a horizontal RecyclerView. I've applied a matrix to the recycler view as an animation, and this works. But I am having trouble mapping it to 3d space, I only have sudo-3d transforms working using matrix.polytopoly() function. See [this documentation for Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html).

Here's a code snippet that produces what I currently have:

```
                int viewWidth = manufacturerRecycler.getWidth();
                int viewHeight = manufacturerRecycler.getHeight();

                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                int w = viewWidth;
                int h = viewHeight ;
                Log.e("Width, height:" , viewWidth + ", "+ viewHeight);
                final float DELTAX = w * 0.15f;
                float[] src = {
                        0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h
                };
                float[] dst = {
                        0, 0, w, 0, w - DELTAX, h, DELTAX, h
                };

                m.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);

                MyAnimation animation = new MyAnimation(m);
                animation.setDuration(0);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                manufacturerRecycler.setAnimation(animation);`
```

Is there any way to use this animation + matrix technique to achieve what I want? It should wrap off each side of the cylinder, and the shadows aren't necessary. (Something like this:)

[image: horizontal wheel picker]

Here is what I have accomplished with the code snippet:

[image: horizontal recyclerview with matrix animation]

Comment: I have solved this. I will share my answer when I have time.

Comment: I did not sufficiently solve it, to where it appears as a true cylinder. I simply was able to improve the above effect, as well as modify spacing between the cells, to give an illusion of warp. But the warp is not matched to a perfect cylinder. I have given up for now...